# Which is the best algorithm to provide moves to solve 15 puzzle?

Tags: ios, algorithm, puzzle

i am working to find the solution steps for a randomly generated "15 puzzle". So tell me which is the best algorithm to use to solve it fast. Provide me approach to do so.

I am making a tree of nodes containing 4*4 array and traversing through all the node which are not yet processed and when i get the solution i stop the iteration.

In viewcontroller i have some code as

```
- (IBAction)getSolution:(id)sender {
while (!appDelegate.isResultFound) {
    TreeNode *node=[self nodeWithLowestCostAndUnproceessedInRootNode];
    [node expandNodeToChilds];
    //break;
}
NSLog(@"Result Found");
if([appDelegate.result isEqualToString:@""])
    NSLog(@"No move required");
else
    NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.result);
```

}

```
-(TreeNode*)nodeWithLowestCostAndUnproceessedInRootNode{
TreeNode *node1;
int lowestCost=200;
for (TreeNode *node in appDelegate.treeNodes) {
    if([node myHeuristicsFunction]<lowestCost&&node.isProcessed==NO){
        node1=node;
        lowestCost=[node.cost intValue];
    }
}
return node1;}
```

and in node class i am expanding the node as (except the move used by the parent)

```
-(void)expandNodeToChilds{
[self checkMovesForEmptyPlace];

if(top.x>=0){
    [self addPuzzleBoxToTreeBySwapingPoint:top withMove:@"Bottom"];
}
if(right.y<=3){
    [self addPuzzleBoxToTreeBySwapingPoint:right withMove:@"Left"];
}
if(bottom.x<=3){
    [self addPuzzleBoxToTreeBySwapingPoint:bottom withMove:@"Top"];
}
if(left.y>=0){
    [self addPuzzleBoxToTreeBySwapingPoint:left withMove:@"Right"];
}
self.isProcessed=true;}
```

Currently i am using manhattan distance with A*, but not getting the result in significant time, app memory increases to 1GB and app crashes.

Comment: I don't see how we can help you with so little information. What are you trying to achieve exactly ? What is "random 15 puzzle" exactly ? What have you tried so far ? Please provide the code of what is done so far.

Comment: Question edited, please have a look. it is not possible to add all the code, i have just added the main snippets of code.

Comment: This question might be better asked on programming.stackexchange.com.

Comment: But i like this site, help me if you can.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that you are looking for the shortest way to reach the goal for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) puzzle. You can use [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) with the [manhattan distance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) between the current board and the goal board as the cost function.

The [following code in Java](http://ideone.com/DCirVQ) implements the algorithm. The function Solver takes as input N, the size of the NxN board and then the corresponding N*N numbers ranging from [0,N^2] giving the locations of the numbers in the 2d grid. It outputs the minimum number of moves that are required and the actual moves. 0 indicates the empty position in the puzzle.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

class Solver{
    private int N ; 
    private int minMoves ;
    public static int[] correctRow;
    public static int[] correctCol;

    private class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
        private Board board ; 
        private int moves ; 
        private Node prevNode ; 
        public Node(Board board,int moves,Node prev){
            this.board = board ; 
            this.moves = moves ; 
            this.prevNode = prev ; 
        }
        public int compareTo(Node that){
            int thisPriority = this.moves+this.board.manhattan() ; 
            int thatPriority = that.moves+that.board.manhattan() ; 
            if(thisPriority<thatPriority){
                return -1 ; 
            }else if(thisPriority>thatPriority){
                return 1 ; 
            }else{
                return 0 ; 
            }
        }
    }

    private Node lastNode ; 
    private boolean solvable ; 

    public Solver(Board initial){
        N = initial.dimension() ; 
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>() ; 
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq2 = new PriorityQueue<Node>() ; 
        pq.add(new Node(initial,0,null)) ; 
        pq2.add(new Node(initial.twin(),0,null)) ; 
        while(true){
            Node removed = pq.poll();
            Node removed2 = pq2.poll();
            if(removed.board.isGoal()){
                minMoves = removed.moves ; 
                lastNode = removed ; 
                solvable = true ; 
                break ; 
            }
            if(removed2.board.isGoal()){
                minMoves = -1 ; 
                solvable = false ; 
                break ; 
            }

            Iterable<Board> neighbors = removed.board.neighbors() ; 
            Iterable<Board> neighbors2 = removed2.board.neighbors() ; 
            for(Board board : neighbors){
                if(removed.prevNode != null && removed.prevNode.board.equals(board) ){
                    continue ; 
                }
                pq.add(new Node(board,removed.moves+1,removed)) ; 
            }
            for(Board board : neighbors2){
                if(removed2.prevNode != null && removed2.prevNode.board.equals(board) ){
                    continue ; 
                }
                pq2.add(new Node(board,removed2.moves+1,removed2)) ; 
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isSolvable(){
        return solvable ; 
    }

    public int moves(){
        return minMoves ; 
    }

    public Iterable<Board> solution(){
        if(!isSolvable()){
            return null ;
        }
        Stack<Board> stack = new Stack<Board>() ; 
        Node node = lastNode ; 
        while(true){
            if(node == null) break ; 
            Board board = node.board ; 
            node = node.prevNode ; 
            stack.push(board) ; 
        }
        return stack ; 
    }

    static void initCorrectRowsCols(int N){
        correctRow = new int[N*N] ; 
        int z = 0 ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++ ){
                correctRow[z++] = i ; 
            }
        }
        z = 0 ; 
        correctCol = new int[N*N] ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++ ){
                correctCol[z++] = j ; 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // create initial board from file
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = in.nextInt();
        initCorrectRowsCols(N);
        int[][] blocks = new int[N][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            blocks[i][j] = in.nextInt();

        Board initial = new Board(blocks);

        // solve the puzzle
        Solver solver = new Solver(initial);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time taken " + (end-start) + " milli seconds");

        // print solution to standard output
        if (!solver.isSolvable())
            System.out.println("No solution possible");
        else {
            System.out.println("Minimum number of moves = " + solver.moves());
            Stack<Board> stack = new Stack<Board>();
            for (Board board : solver.solution())
                stack.push(board);
            while(!stack.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(stack.pop());
            }
        }
    }
}

class Board{
    private int[][] array ; 
    private int N ;
    int emptyRow;
    int emptyCol;
    boolean reached;
    int manhattan = 0;

    public Board(int[][] blocks){
        N = blocks.length ; 
        array = new int[N][N] ;
        reached = true;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++ ) {
                array[i][j] = blocks[i][j] ;
                if(array[i][j] == 0){
                    emptyRow = i;
                    emptyCol = j;
                }
                if(array[i][j] != N*i + j+1){
                    if(!(i==N-1 && j==N-1)){
                        reached = false;
                    }
                }
                int num = array[i][j] ; 
                if(num==0){
                    continue ; 
                }
                int indManhattan = Math.abs(Solver.correctRow[num-1] - i) 
                        + Math.abs(Solver.correctCol[num-1]-j) ; 
                manhattan += indManhattan ;
            }
        }
    }

    public int dimension(){
        return N ; 
    }

    public int hamming(){
        int outOfPlace = 0 ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++ ){
                if(i==N-1 && j==N-1) {
                    break ; 
                }
                if(array[i][j] != i*N+j+1){
                    outOfPlace++ ; 
                }
            }
        }
        return outOfPlace ; 
    }

    public int manhattan(){
        return manhattan ; 
    }

    public boolean isGoal(){
        return reached ; 
    }

    public Board twin(){
        int[][] newArray = new int[N][N] ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++ ){
                newArray[i][j] = array[i][j] ; 
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ ) {
            if(newArray[i][0]==0 || newArray[i][5]==0){
                continue ; 
            }
                int temp = newArray[i][0] ; 
                newArray[i][0] = newArray[i][6] ; 
                newArray[i][7] = temp ; 
                break ; 

        }
        return new Board(newArray) ; 
    }

    public boolean equals(Object y){
        if(y==this){
            return true ; 
        }
        if(y == null){
            return false ; 
        }
        if(y.getClass() != this.getClass()){
            return false ; 
        }
        Board that = (Board)y ; 
        if(that.array.length != this.array.length){
            return false ;
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ) {
            for(int j =  0 ; j < N ; j++ ) {
                if(that.array[i][j] != this.array[i][j] ){
                    return false ; 
                }
            }
        }
        return true ; 
    }

    public Iterable<Board> neighbors(){
        Queue<Board> q = new ArrayDeque<Board>() ; 
        int firstIndex0 = 0 ; 
        int secondIndex0 = 0 ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++ ) {
                if(array[i][j] == 0){
                    firstIndex0 = i ; 
                    secondIndex0 = j ; 
                    break ; 
                }
            }
        }
        if(secondIndex0-1>-1){
            int[][] newArr = getCopy() ; 
            exch(newArr,firstIndex0,secondIndex0,firstIndex0,secondIndex0-1) ; 
            q.add(new Board(newArr)) ; 
        }
        if(secondIndex0+1<N){
            int[][] newArr = getCopy() ; 
            exch(newArr,firstIndex0,secondIndex0,firstIndex0,secondIndex0+1) ; 
            q.add(new Board(newArr)) ; 
        }
        if(firstIndex0-1>-1){
            int[][] newArr = getCopy() ; 
            exch(newArr,firstIndex0,secondIndex0,firstIndex0-1,secondIndex0) ;     
            q.add(new Board(newArr)) ; 
        }
        if(firstIndex0+1<N){
            int[][] newArr = getCopy() ; 
            exch(newArr,firstIndex0,secondIndex0,firstIndex0+1,secondIndex0) ; 
            q.add(new Board(newArr)) ; 
        }
        return q ; 
    }

    private int[][] getCopy(){
        int[][] copy = new int[N][N] ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++ ){
                copy[i][j] = array[i][j] ; 
            }
        }
        return copy ; 
    }

    private void exch(int[][] arr, int firstIndex,int secIndex,int firstIndex2,int secIndex2){
        int temp = arr[firstIndex][secIndex] ; 
        arr[firstIndex][secIndex] = arr[firstIndex2][secIndex2] ;  
        arr[firstIndex2][secIndex2] = temp ; 
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder() ; 
        s.append(N + "\n") ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0 ; j  < N ; j++ ) {
                s.append(String.format("%4d",array[i][j])) ; 
            }
            s.append("\n") ; 
        }
        return s.toString() ; 
    }
}
```

So for the input

```
3
   7   8   5
   4   0   2
   3   6   1
```

The algorithm generates the output

```
Minimum number of moves = 28
3
   7   8   5
   4   0   2
   3   6   1

3
   7   0   5
   4   8   2
   3   6   1

3
   7   5   0
   4   8   2
   3   6   1

3
   7   5   2
   4   8   0
   3   6   1

3
   7   5   2
   4   0   8
   3   6   1

3
   7   5   2
   4   6   8
   3   0   1

3
   7   5   2
   4   6   8
   3   1   0

3
   7   5   2
   4   6   0
   3   1   8

3
   7   5   2
   4   0   6
   3   1   8

3
   7   5   2
   0   4   6
   3   1   8

3
   0   5   2
   7   4   6
   3   1   8

3
   5   0   2
   7   4   6
   3   1   8

3
   5   4   2
   7   0   6
   3   1   8

3
   5   4   2
   7   1   6
   3   0   8

3
   5   4   2
   7   1   6
   0   3   8

3
   5   4   2
   0   1   6
   7   3   8

3
   5   4   2
   1   0   6
   7   3   8

3
   5   0   2
   1   4   6
   7   3   8

3
   0   5   2
   1   4   6
   7   3   8

3
   1   5   2
   0   4   6
   7   3   8

3
   1   5   2
   4   0   6
   7   3   8

3
   1   5   2
   4   3   6
   7   0   8

3
   1   5   2
   4   3   6
   7   8   0

3
   1   5   2
   4   3   0
   7   8   6

3
   1   5   2
   4   0   3
   7   8   6

3
   1   0   2
   4   5   3
   7   8   6

3
   1   2   0
   4   5   3
   7   8   6

3
   1   2   3
   4   5   0
   7   8   6

3
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   0
```

I would also like to mention that

- Finding a shortest solution to an N-by-N slider puzzle is [NP-Hard](http://www.aaai.org/Library/AAAI/1986/aaai86-027.php), so it's unlikely that an efficient solution exists.
- If you are not looking for a shortest path solution but any solution that runs fast in the input then [this](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ccalabro/essays/15_puzzle.pdf) paper describes an algorithm that guarantees to perform at most N^3 moves.

Thus although the solution I have given runs fast on most of the inputs, it may fail on other difficult inputs.

Also note that not all puzzles are solvable. For the puzzles that cannot be solved, the algorithm prints that the puzzle cannot be solved.

PS. The algorithm implemented above follows the guidelines of [this programming assignment](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos226/assignments/8puzzle.html).

Comment: have you tried this code for 15 puzzle, i think it won't work efficiently.

Comment: What makes you say so? Have you tested the code on ideone for any input? You can test for this input http://pastebin.com/mQjeqbLf which has the shortest path of 40 moves.

Comment: Solver.node class write error

Comment: Please access this link. The program runs fine http://ideone.com/DCirVQ

Comment: please tell me what technique actually you are using, the manhattan distance or pattern database?

Comment: Manhattan distance. What do you mean by pattern database?

Comment: pattern database is also a heuristics function like manhattan

Comment: Please refer to the link at the end of the answer. I have basically used A* search as it has been explained on that webpage.

Comment: Why you are doing so in twin,  if(newArray[i][0]==0 || newArray[i][1]==0){
                continue ; 
            }
                int temp = newArray[i][0] ; 
                newArray[i][0] = newArray[i][1] ; 
                newArray[i][1] = temp ; 
                break ; 
            
        }

Comment: I don't find where you are utilising the manhattan distance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52774/discussion-between-invin-and-ravi-gupta)

Comment: Not working for all inputs .. error time limit exceeds

Comment: 2   7   0   3
 5  15  14   1
 6  11  12   8
13   4   9  10 try it

Comment: As I have said in my answer that this problem is NP-Hard. Which means that there are no guaranteed efficient solutions which solve the problem in polynomial time. If you are looking for any set of moves that solves the puzzle(and not a minimal one), then try the O(N^3) runtime algorithm that I have linked to.

Comment: Actually i have tried to convert your code to objective c but not able to get success in running that.

Comment: I dont know objective C. So cant help you on that.