# What would be the right approach for implementing an algorithm for a 15 puzzle?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, puzzle

I am thinking of the best approach for this problem ... Any help would be appreciated. I'm specifically looking for a solution involving parallelization.

Comment: What is a 15 puzzle?  Have you tried looking this up already using a search engine?

Comment: Is this the sliding numbers in a 4x4 area puzzle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630620/which-is-the-best-algorithm-to-provide-moves-to-solve-15-puzzle

Comment: FYI, a simple google of "15 puzzle solver algorithm" gave a treasure trove of info.

Comment: A finite state machine-type implementation might work.  Every possible board configuration is a state.  From every state there are a maximum of four new states to which you could move.  The parallelization follows naturally from solving each of those states independently, though if each sub-solution runs entirely independently you're probably going to solve the same state a whole bunch of times.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE.  OP WANTS HELP REGARDING A PARALLEL SOLUTION.  THE "ALREADY EXISTING ANSWER" OFFERS NO PARALLELISM OR ANY RELATED INSIGHTS.

Comment: Here is an answer that addresses the parallelism issue directly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1866161/120163

Answer (score 1):

Asking for **the best** approach is always quite hard to answer. (Actually impossible for the most questions.)

In general, the **A*-algorithm** is a good approach for this. There is a lot of information about this algorithm and even some implementations for the puzzle you mentioned are easily accessable.